# Can printf print defined strings?

Tags: c, string, printing, character, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to scan a character, pass it to a char array and then if a is defined as string to print that string? Below is the code, (which gets the warning "cast to pointer from integer of different size") 
Thanks in advance

```
 char *a = "alpha";
 int main()
 {
     char *A[80];
     char ch;
     printf("enter message");
     scanf(" %c", &ch);
     A[0] = (char *) ch;
     printf("%s\t", A[0]);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `%s` wants a c-string: null terminated array of chars... `ch` is a single char. BTW you are assigning a char to a pointer, as the compiler is trying to tell you with that warning.

Comment: Sorry, I conldn't understand your question well, especially the part "print defined strings" and "if a is defined as string to print that string". Could you explain some more?

Comment: To pass scanned chracter to a char array, you need modifiable char array. String literal is not modifiable.

Comment: Yes and sorry for that. I want to enter some characters and if 'a' is entered I want it to print 'alpha'. Im asking if this is possible or if I should do it using if.

Comment: %s cannot print character. if you want enter 'a' should print alpha then using if..else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want might be something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* word candidate list: terminated by NULL */
const char* a[] = {
    "alpha",
    NULL
};

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int i;
    /* read input */
    printf("enter message");
    if (scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1)
    {
        puts("read error");
        return 1;
    }
    /* search for matching word(s) */
    for (i = 0; a[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        /* if the first character of the word is what is scanned, print the word */
        if (a[i][0]  == ch)
        {
            printf("%s\t", a[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you probably meant to write:

```
int main()
{
  char A[80];
  char ch;
  printf("enter message");
  scanf(" %c", &ch);
  A[0] = ch;
  printf("%c\t", A[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

You didn't declare you array `A` right, and when you print a `char` (`A[0]`), you should use `%c` in `printf()` function.

If you wanted to print it as an string (`%s` modifier), you need to NULL-terminate it, which means adding `\0` at the end of the string.

Comment: yes but i want it to print 'alpha' if 'a' is scaned

Comment: When `a` is the first letter, or when the string contains `a`? Or something else? You need to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a string from a char and print it using "%s" then, you need to do something like below:

```
char *a = "alpha";
 int main()
 {
     char A[80] = {0};
     char ch;
     printf("enter message");
     scanf(" %c", &ch);
     A[0] = ch;
     printf("%s\t", A);

     return 0;
 }
```

The mistakes in your code were:

1. You were declaring an array of char pointers instead of an array of 
   char
2. You were assigning a `char` typecasted as `char *`
3. Your print statement was incorrect due to the declaration of char
   array being wrong.

Please note that I have initialized the array `A` to 0, so that the string is automatically null terminated.

Based on your comment, the updated code for your expected solution:

```
char *a = "alpha";
 int main()
 {
     char ch;
     printf("enter message");
     scanf(" %c", &ch);
     if (ch == 'a')
       printf("%s\t", a);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it but it prints the scanned character. (Even if I enter 'a' it prints just 'a' and not "alpha").

Comment: Please see the updated solution. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Do you mean the user should enter the variable name and then it should print that variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I'm now on mobile phone. I haven't tested it.

```
int main()
{
    char A[80];
    char ch;
    printf("enter message");
    A[0] = (char)fgetc(stdin);
    printf("\n%c\n", A[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To enter a char, use fputc() not scanf(). And in case ch is a string, you have to define ch as an array or a pointer to char with allocation and change printf modifer from %c to %s.